# Connecting to Parse using TCP IP?

Tags: parse-platform

We have a `Parse` server(`Parse.com`) in which we would like to write data to, from a hardware device,using `rest API`
The hardware device is using `TCP` connection to send data to the server .
Things we have to set when sending data is :

```
"TCP","184.xxx.xxx.xxx",80 (the ip of the server)
```

Now, how can i know what is the ip of our app in parse to connect to it and send data ?

I have tried :

```
"TCP","https://api.parse.com",80
```

got `DNS failed` ..

also tried with port 443 with same error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with :

```
"TCP","api.parse.com",443
```